# How to set a button in center bottom in Android XML Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put a button on center & bottom of the linear layout. I used below codes, & it's not working. Can u guys help me out?

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:background="#C01831"
            android:onClick="meonFb"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Talk to Developer" />
```

And the mother layout is,

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="#f9f9f9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try `android:gravity="center|bottom"`

Comment: this takes the button text center & bottom

Comment: ... which is what you asked for: `set a button in center bottom`

Comment: the button should be center bottom of the layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code will place button center-bottom in the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="#f9f9f9"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:background="#C01831"
        android:onClick="meonFb"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Talk to Developer" />

</LinearLayout>
```